# How to add .txt extension to multiple files?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I have a folder with many files that i need to add a `.txt` extension.
For example:

```
Filename: 
Current Filename - A1234.FILE.B12345.C12345 
Desired Filename - A1234.FILE.B12345.C12345.txt
```

I tried to use cmd prompt by using: `ren *.**.txt`, and it just removed the "C12345" from the filename.

Answer (score 0):

If Powershell is an option, will this work for you?  Remove the `-WhatIf` after you confirm it's behaving as expected.

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($_.Name + ".txt") -WhatIf -Verbose }
```

Or more succinctly:

```
dir | %{ Rename-Item $_ -NewName ($_.Name + ".txt") -WhatIf -Verbose }
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name + '.txt'}
```

[Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6) has alias `gci`.`-File` ecludes folders.

[Rename-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-6) has alias `ren`. Using a scriptblock for the `NewName` parameter allows the Cmdlet to work with pipeline input.

Short version:

```
gci -file | ren -N {$_.Name + '.txt'}
```